# Не приходит сообщение в post запросе

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa.js

Код бэкенда:

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const Router = require('koa-router');

const app = new Koa();
const router = new Router();

app.use(require('koa-static')('./public'));
app.use(require('koa-bodyparser')());

router.post('/send', async (ctx) => {
    const message = ctx.request.body.message;
    console.log(message);
});

app.use(router.routes());

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('server started!');
});
```

С клиента запрос отправляется так:

```
publish.onsubmit = function() {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "/send", true);
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({message: this.elements.message.value}));
    this.elements.message.value = '';
    return false;
};
```

Запросы уходят успешно с сообщениями. Приходят и успешно ловятся роутером, но `console.log(message)` постоянно `undefined`. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема оказалась элементарной. Нужно было всего лишь явно указать Content-Type в клиенте:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/send", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({message: this.elements.message.value}));
```